# How can I change the mvc ajax form parameters in the posted-to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For example, if I wanted to change the UpdateTarget or the InsertionMode in the controller after the form was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by not setting updatetargetid and insertmode, instead you just need to use onsuccess and oncomplete event, and then when the controller return the value back, you just need to add the targetid and insertmode into the return data (i.e json), then in your function of handling return result, you just need to read these values.

Answer (score 1):

Controller has no information where and how calling JavaScript code is going to insert controller's result into the page. So controller is unable to change it.